# Conditional statements and nesting in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

*Edited to reflect ongoing discussion.*

From my server section I want to use a different formula, depending on a radioButton selection that's called `input$beamSupport` and furthermore change the formula, depending on the value of `x`. I'm stuck on the syntax, however.

I also know that I could trim some of the code by simply stating "else...", but I want to have the possibility to expand.

Right now I get the error message *"Error in if: argument is of length zero"*

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Style tags for changing the slider
    tags$style(HTML(".irs-bar {background: none}")),
    tags$style(HTML(".irs-bar {border-top: none}")),
    tags$style(HTML(".irs-bar {border-bottom: none}")),
    tags$style(HTML(".irs-bar-edge {border: none}")),
    tags$style(HTML(".irs-bar-edge {background: none}")),


mainPanel(
    titlePanel("Beam Deflection Calculator"),

    radioButtons("beamSupport",
                 label = ("Beam support type"),
                 choices = list("Simply supported" = 1,
                                "Cantilever" = 2),
                 selected = 1),

    numericInput("num_W", # Load force, W
                 label = "Enter load force in N.",
                 value = 1),

    numericInput("num_l", # Length of beam, l
                 label = "Enter beam length in m.",
                 value = 10),

    numericInput("num_I", # Intertial moment, I (caps i)
                 label = "Enter moment of inertia in m^4.",
                 value = 0.001),

    numericInput("num_E",
                 label = "Enter Young's modulus in GPa.",
                 value = 200),

    uiOutput("slider"), # Sliders for a and x

    textOutput("text_calc")
)
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$slider <- renderUI({
        tagList( # Need this for multiple reactive sliders
            sliderInput("slider_a",
                        label = "Choose position, where to apply force, starting from left, in m.",
                        min = 0,
                        max = input$num_l,
                        value = 5,
                        step = 0.1),

            sliderInput("slider_x",
                        label = "Calculate the deflection, at position starting from left, in m.",
                        min = 0,
                        max = input$num_l,
                        value = 5,
                        step = 0.1)
        )
    })

    output$text_calc <- renderText({
        W <- input$num_W
        l <- input$num_l
        I <- input$num_I
        E <- input$num_E * 10^9
        a <- input$slider_a
        x <- input$slider_x

        cond <- x < a

        if (input$beamSupport == 1){
            if (cond){
                return(paste("The deflection is =",
                      ((W*(l-a)*x)/(6*E*I*l))*(l**2-x**2-(l-a)**2)
                ))
            }
            else{
                return(paste("The deflection is =",
                      ((W*a*(l-x))/(6*E*I*l))*(l**2-(l-x)**2-a**2)
                ))
            }
        }

        if (input$beamSupport == 2){
            if (cond){
                return(paste("The deflection is =",
                      ((W*x**2)/(6*E*I))*(3*a-x)
                ))
            }
            else{
                return(paste("The deflection is =",
                      ((W*a**2)/(6*E*I))*(3*x-a)
                ))
            }
        }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, also note that when you use `renderUI` that will be will get evaluated after the initial parameters are loaded so your `slider_a` and `slider_x` will be null until then.

```
#rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Style tags for changing the slider
  tags$style(HTML(".irs-bar {background: none}")),
  tags$style(HTML(".irs-bar {border-top: none}")),
  tags$style(HTML(".irs-bar {border-bottom: none}")),
  tags$style(HTML(".irs-bar-edge {border: none}")),
  tags$style(HTML(".irs-bar-edge {background: none}")),


  mainPanel(
    titlePanel("Beam Deflection Calculator"),

    radioButtons("beamSupport",
                 label = ("Beam support type"),
                 choices = list("Simply supported" = 1,
                                "Cantilever" = 2),
                 selected = 1),

    numericInput("num_W", # Load force, W
                 label = "Enter load force in N.",
                 value = 1),

    numericInput("num_l", # Length of beam, l
                 label = "Enter beam length in m.",
                 value = 10),

    numericInput("num_I", # Intertial moment, I (caps i)
                 label = "Enter moment of inertia in m^4.",
                 value = 0.001),

    numericInput("num_E",
                 label = "Enter Young's modulus in GPa.",
                 value = 200),

    uiOutput("slider"), # Sliders for a and x

    textOutput("text_calc")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$slider <- renderUI({
    tagList( # Need this for multiple reactive sliders
      sliderInput("slider_a",
                  label = "Choose position, where to apply force, starting from left, in m.",
                  min = 0,
                  max = input$num_l,
                  value = 5,
                  step = 0.1),

      sliderInput("slider_x",
                  label = "Calculate the deflection, at position starting from left, in m.",
                  min = 0,
                  max = input$num_l,
                  value = 5,
                  step = 0.1)
    )
  })

  output$text_calc <- renderText({
    if(is.null(input$slider_a) || is.null(input$slider_x)){
      return()
    }
    W <- input$num_W
    l <- input$num_l
    I <- input$num_I
    E <- input$num_E * 10^9
    a <- input$slider_a
    x <- input$slider_x

    cond <- x < a

    if (input$beamSupport == 1){
      if (cond){
        return(paste("The deflection is =",
                     ((W*(l-a)*x)/(6*E*I*l))*(l**2-x**2-(l-a)**2)
        ))
      }
      else{
        return(paste("The deflection is =",
                     ((W*a*(l-x))/(6*E*I*l))*(l**2-(l-x)**2-a**2)
        ))
      }
    }

    if (input$beamSupport == 2){
      if (cond){
        return(paste("The deflection is =",
                     ((W*x**2)/(6*E*I))*(3*a-x)
        ))
      }
      else{
        return(paste("The deflection is =",
                     ((W*a**2)/(6*E*I))*(3*x-a)
        ))
      }
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work now. I still get *"Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero"* though. What does it mean?

Comment: If you run my code, everything is working fine, you must be doing something extra. What this means is that you're not taking care of the `null`, such as: `if(input$SOME_INPUT== null){return()}

Comment: I can't find the error. I've done the exact same thing as you, except for some renaming. All parameters have default values that are non-zero, so where would I need to include null? The full output is `Stack trace (innermost first):
    79: renderText [~/Desktop/beamDeflection/beamDeflection.R#85]
    78: func
    77: origRenderFunc
    76: output$text_calc
     1: runApp`

Comment: Done. See original post.